# On effective constructions in the functional analysis of Volterra's integration operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, approximation-theory

Let $V: L^2(0,1) \to L^2(0,1)$ be the Volterra integration operator: $V(f)(x) := \int_0^x f(t) \, dt$.

*Is there a universal function $C(L,\varepsilon) < \infty$ such that the following uniform version [of this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/297172/what-are-the-possible-l-infty-closures-of-an-integration-invariant-linear-s) holds? For any continuous function $f \in C([0,1])$ satisfying $1 \leq f \leq L$ on the whole segment $[0,1]$, there exist real numbers $a_0, a_1,\ldots, a_M$ such that
$$
(1) \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \sum_{k=0}^M \frac{|a_k|}{k!} \leq C(L,\varepsilon)
$$
and
$$
(2) \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad  \Big\| 1 - \sum_{k =0}^M a_k V^k(f) \Big\|_{L^2(0,1)} \leq \varepsilon.
$$*

(The $a_k/k!$ terms in (1) are natural once one notes that the operator $V^k$ has norm $\leq 1/k!$.)

[**A:** Yes! As @fedja explained in the comments, a compactness argument applies non-constructively to show that (1) is an automatic consequence of (2). Arguing for contradiction, suppose to the contrary that there is a sequence $f_n$ with $1 \leq f_n \leq L$ that requires an arbitrarily large sum in (1). The set $\{ Vg \mid |g| \leq L \}$ is compact in $C[0,1]$, since it consists of continuously differentiable functions of a bounded $C^1$ norm. Hence, on passing to a subsequence, we may assume that $Vf_n \to f$ uniformly to a continuous function $f \in C[0,1]$, and since all $f_n \geq 1$, this limit function $f$ certainly fulfills a relation (2) with $\varepsilon$ replaced by $\varepsilon / 2$, by the qualitative results cited below the line. If now $n \to \infty$, this is in contradiction with our assumption that all relations (2) for $f_n$ must have a divergent sum in (1). ]

**Q.:** *What could be said about $C(L,0.5)$ as a function of $L$?*

---

The existence of *some* approximation (2), not necessarily satisfying the uniform condition (1), is known (following M.S. Brodskii) as the *unicellularity of the Volterra integration operator*, and has (it seems) essentially three fundamentally distinct proofs. One approach (Agmon, Kalisch, Donoghue, Sakhnovic...) is via zero distribution properties of entire functions; indeed the qualitative result (2) [turns out to be equivalent](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X6280002X) to the [Titchmarsh convolution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titchmarsh_convolution_theorem). Another proof ([Sarason](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022247X65900351)) derives the existence of a relation (2) from Beurling's characterization of the closed invariant subspaces of the unilateral shift of $\ell^2$. A [third proof](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=rm&paperid=6089&option_lang=rus), due to Brodskii and Livsic, is purely functional analytic and based on their spectral resolution theory for abstract non-self adjoint completely continuous operators $V$ of a Hilbert space $H$ having a single point as their spectrum. (The total linear ordering property of the closed invariant subspaces of $V$ holds more generally for all such operators that, in addition, fulfill $\ker(V) \cap \ker(V^*) = \{0\}$ and $\dim\frac{V - V^*}{2i}(H) = 1$.)

To my surprise, I find that apparently none of these three existential schemes of proofs admits an obvious effective variant that says anything about the size of the coefficients $a_k$ used in the representation (2). I would like to know more about the constant $C(L,\varepsilon)$ of this putative statement, particularly as a function of $L$ for a fixed value $\varepsilon$ (is it $O(L)$? $o(L)$?). For a start,  I have to understand if there are constructive techniques of functional analysis that would give this refinement, perhaps in combination with one of the existing solutions of (2).

Comment: That would be a bit too much because the norm of $V^k$ in $C[0,0.5]$ is only $\frac 1{k!}2^{-k}$ and you can kill as many low powers as you wish by taking a fast oscillating function (like $\cos Nx$ with huge $N$), so if this is what you really need, you are out of luck. If you can get away with less, let us know what it is.

Comment: @fedja: Thank you for pointing this out: the condition $f(0) = 1$ and $|f| \leq L$ is indeed not the relevant one, in view of these oscillating examples. I was thinking that I should bound $f$ from below somehow, not only at $0$. For my example I can assume $1 \leq f \leq L$ on all of $[0,1]$; I'll edit as this amendment seems to make a difference. In any case, I am curious about *any* way of quantifying (2), in terms of some such relevant condition about $f$.

Comment: Still bad. Take $f(x)=2-\cos Nx$. For the same reason, as before, under condition (1), large $k$ do not matter on $[0,0.5]$ while small $k\ge 1$ give you almost a polynomial, which, since it has bounded degree, cannot catch up with the oscillations of $\cos$ for large enough $N$...

Comment: @fedja: I am confused by this example, for aren't the small *strictly positive* ($k \neq 0$) iterates $V(\cos{Nx}) = N^{-1} \sin(Nx), \,  V^2(\cos(Nx)) = N^{-2} - N^{-2}\cos(Nx)$ etc., all essentially negligible in magnitude (while of course wildly oscillating - that doesn't harm when the magnitude is this small), once $N$ is very large? We are then reduced to approximating the constant $1$ in $L^2(0,1)$ by a small degree polynomial without free term and with fairly small coefficients, which is possible. I apologize if I am overlooking something again.

Comment: (We just abstain from using $V^0(f) = f$ in this example, but make use of the cancellations from the oscillations of $f$ in the further iterates $V^1(f), V^2(f), \ldots$. I agree that $a_0 \approx 0$ necessarily in this example.)

Comment: You are right. For some reason I thought that we were approximating in $C$ rather than in $L^2$. Then *some* $C(L,\varepsilon)$ exists. Indeed, after the first application of $V$ and passing to the closure, you get a compact family of functions each of which generates the entire space (in $L^2$, but not in $C$). So just find some coefficients for each of them and use the fact that they work in some neighborhood.

Comment: Yes, the previous example demonstrated that it certainly makes a difference that the approximation is intended in $L^2$ and not in $C$. Thanks very much, this appears to be making sense, the one thing that bothers me on a first look is how the lower bound of the condition $1 \leq f \leq L$ (clearly necessary for the $C(L,\varepsilon)$ statement to hold) gets used in the compactness argument with $\{ Vf \mid 1 \leq f \leq L \}$.

Comment: It is used not for *compactness* but for the statement that *every* function in the closure of the corresponding family of $Vf$ generates the entire space while in the first counterexample $0$ was in the closure (which is exactly what I used).

Comment: @fedja: Now I see - this is neat - we may simply extract a limit $Vf_n \to Vf$ from a sequence of hypothetical counterexamples, make a construction (2) for $f$ and just take an $f_n$ farther enough along the sequence to derive the contradiction. I was a little confused at first as I presumed the argument would start with choosing some finite $\epsilon$-net from the compact set $\{ Vf \mid |f| \leq L \}$, whereas we are really letting $\epsilon \to 0$ and passing to a sequence for the contradiction, even with the fixed value of $\varepsilon$.